# JavaFX 8 - synchronize columns on two vertically stacked TableViews

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX 8 and my user-interface requires two TableViews, one positioned vertically above the other (i.e., both children of a `VBox`).  The `VBox` itself is in a `SplitPane`, so that the widths of the tables can grow or shrink.

The two tables each have 5 columns and these 5 columns are the same between the two tables.

Here is what I need:

1) Columns 1,2,4, and 5 in each table should be sized according to the minimum of either (A) their own computed size (i.e., based on their contents) or (B) the computed size of the same column in the other table.

2) Column 3 in each table should take up whatever space is left.

The practical end of all this is that all the columns are always aligned vertically between the two tables and that columns 1,2,4, and 5 are always big enough to display their contents.

I don't need code, but can anyone suggest a strategy for accomplishing this (e.g., bind property A here to property B there, or whatever)?  I'd like to avoid a long or complicated system of listeners keeping everything in sync.

If it makes it easier, none of the columns need to be user-resizable.

#### Update

The reason there are two tables instead of just one (which would make this whole thing easier) is that there is a region between them that displays some summary information.  If it is possible to display that summary information a `TableRow` (which could be forced to have 5 columns), that could be a workable answer too.

#### Update #2

Also keep in mind that either, both, or neither of the tables might have a vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a third, invisible table that has all the rows.  I made the third table's height very small so that it is guaranteed to have a vertical scroll bar.

From there, I just had to get the columns sized correctly for that one (hidden) table - which is a problem that there are many solutions already posted -- and then bind the `prefWidth` of all the visible columns to their analogues in the hidden one.

So, it's basically:

```
SplitPane
  -> StackPane
     -> VBox
        -> Top TableView (column widths bound to Hidden TableView)
        -> Bottom TableView (column widths bound to Hidden TableView)
     -> Hidden TableView (height 10px and `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`)
```

The `StackPane` is required so that the hidden TableView does not actually take up any space on the screen.  (Another option was to make it unmanaged, but that was more work).

It works well enough, but definitely seems a kludge.  I won't accept my own answer (if that's even possible) ... I'd still like a better one!